# Migrating from formik-material-ui 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: reactjs, formik, formik-material-ui

I have an existing form, using, using a custom component that is working under formik-material-ui 1.0:

```
const MyCheckbox = ({ field, form, label, ...rest }) => {
  const { name, value: formikValue } = field
  const { setFieldValue } = form

  const handleChange = event => {
    const values = formikValue || []
    const index = values.indexOf(rest.value)
    if (index === -1) {
      values.push(rest.value)
    } else {
      values.splice(index, 1)
    }
    setFieldValue(name, values)
  }

  return (
    <label>
      <Checkbox onChange={handleChange} checked={formikValue.indexOf(rest.value) !== -1} {...rest} />
      <span>{label}</span>
    </label>
  )
}
```

and being rendered using this line:

```
<Field component={MyCheckbox} name="sectionChoices" value={label} label={label} />
```

As described by the [documentation](https://stackworx.github.io/formik-material-ui/docs/guide/migrating) I've removed the `Field` import, and the `component` property, but the remainder has me stuck. If Field is no longer available, what should I be doing in the `MyCheckbox`? I've tried:

```
import { Formik, Form, useForm } from 'formik'

const MyCheckbox = ({ field, label, ...rest }) => {
  const { name, value: formikValue } = field
  const form = useForm()
  const { setFieldValue } = form

  const handleChange = event => {
    const values = formikValue || []
    const index = values.indexOf(rest.value)
    if (index === -1) {
      values.push(rest.value)
    } else {
      values.splice(index, 1)
    }
    setFieldValue(name, values)
  }

  return (
    <label>
      <Checkbox onChange={handleChange} checked={formikValue.indexOf(rest.value) !== -1} {...rest} />
      <span>{label}</span>
    </label>
  )
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Attempted import error: 'useForm' is not exported from 'formik'.
```

My `package.json` file has the following relevant dependencies:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "formik": "^2.0.3",
    "formik-material-ui": "^2.0.0-alpha.3",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.1",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "typeface-roboto": "^0.0.75",
    "yup": "^0.28.1"
  },
  ...
```

### }

Migration instructions:

As stated about, I've using the migration instructions from[here](https://stackworx.github.io/formik-material-ui/docs/guide/migrating), a screenshot from which I also add.

[image: Migration instructions including hooks for useForm and useField]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hook called `useForm` in formik api, I think you're mixing it with `useFormik` hook.
`formik-material-ui` is using `useField` hook internally so you don't have to wrap your component with formik's `Field` component, instead you can directly render your `MyCheckbox` like:
`<MyCheckbox name="sectionChoices" value={label} label={label} />`

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing `<MyCheckbox name="sectionChoices" value={label} label={label} />` . As for the `useForm` hook, this is directly from the documentation page as linked: `Rename fieldToTextField to useFieldToTextField
Add import {useField} from 'formik' is you need access to field helpers
Add import {useForm} from 'formik' is you need access to form helpers`

Comment: use `useFormik` instead of `useForm`.

Comment: I just want to clarify - you believe that the instructions themselves are wrong (see screen shot)? I will test this morning.